# Flip PSTricks axis labels upside-down?

Tags: pstricks, labels, pst-plot

In PSTricks, is there a way to flip the axis labels upside down? Or achieve the same effect by some other means? Thanks.

[edit]

Here's my document so far. I just need the numbers upside down. It is going to be part of a 3D scene, and I will be looking at the axes from the opposite direction.

[edit]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nopageno,pst-node,pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\psset{linecolor=black,linewidth=1pt,arrowsize=8pt,unit=1px}
\begin{pspicture}(-15,-15)(150,15)

  % Axes
  \psaxes[Dx=32,Dy=32,labels=none]{-}(-128,-128)(-128,-128)(128,128)
  \psset{linewidth=2pt}
  \psaxes[Dx=32,Dy=32,labels=all,ticksize=8pt,tickstyle=bottom,Ox=-128,Oy=-128]{-}(-128,-128)(-128,-128)(128,128)
  \uput{10pt}[70](-160,0){\psscalebox{1.25}{\itshape a}}
  \uput{10pt}[0](0,-160){\psscalebox{1.25}{\itshape b}}

\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you attach your hand drawn sketch to this question?

Comment: Updated with the document so far.

Comment: You should also post your code so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot,graphicx}
\def\pshlabel#1{\rotatebox{90}{#1}}
\def\psvlabel#1{\rotatebox{90}{#1}}
\begin{document}

\psset{linewidth=1pt,arrowsize=8pt,unit=1pt}
\begin{pspicture}(-150,-150)(150,150)
    \psset{linewidth=2pt}
    \psaxes[Dx=32,Dy=32,ticksize=-4pt 8pt,Ox=-128,Oy=-128]%
      (-128,-128)(-128,-128)(128,128)
    \uput{10pt}[70](-160,0){\large\itshape a}
    \uput{10pt}[0](0,-160){\large\itshape b}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Some comments: This method seems to rotate the entire document, not just the axis labels. Is there a way to avoid that? Can the 'a' and 'b' text labels be rotated as well?

Comment: Never mind. It seems to be working now.